# Spring boot or Vertx or any other framework for reactive micro-service development

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, vert.x, reactive, light-4j

I want to convert my monolith application to microservices because it is more in size and all the modules are tightly coupled in the same. I went through many documents but still not able to figure it out which framework should I use.

My Use cases:-

- Microservices I am developing will be bundled in one container and
  will be deployed on the customer's system, So the size of the Jar is
  the first constraint.
- I want all these to communicate over a single channel and if channel
  gets down or it should be handled gracefully.
- I have the few use cases where the request will be taking the time to
  complete around 15 to 20 minutes.

Here some finding from me about framework benchmarking

- https://github.com/networknt/microservices-framework-benchmark
- [https://craftsmen.nl/memory-usage-6-popular-rest-server-frameworks-compared/](https://craftsmen.nl/memory-usage-6-popular-rest-server-frameworks-compared)

Comment: Out of those is Vert.x the only microservice-enabling toolkit. If your services need to both communicate to each other AND scale, I don't see any real high-level alternative to Vert.x

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to design a microservices architecture, the only constraint is to have two or more independent applications that communicates each other.
Having this in mind you probably have to consider more questions appart form the size of the artifacts.

- The whole system must be highly available, resilient and scalable? perhaps the best option would be a reactive architecture based in message communication for example lagom
- If you are confortable with rest/synchronouns communication between services, you could use spring boot applications communicated over http calls using probably some king of circuit breaker library.
- If you want more lightweight artifacts and faster to run micronauts is a good option.

There are many other frameworks that can help to develop your architecture but the most important thing is discover the real requirements of the application to better chose among them.

Answer (score 0):

Both technologies are fine. You can choose Spring Cloud and also use vert.x.
Spring boot also support reactive programming.
 You can have servlet based microservices and netty based microservices, based on your needs.

I have example integrated vertx and spring boot together

https://github.com/armdev/reactive-web

But my suggestion is to start from Spring boot/cloud. Dont make complexity from the first! Start with Spring cloud and docker/compose.